# How to check if a DropDown with Fill In option is empty or not?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, validation, dropdown

I have a dropdown "product category" with Fill in option. But when I set validation on it as a mandatory field using javascript ie I check,

```
if (dropdown =="" || fillin=="")
    alert(required message)
```

but this doesn't works because even if focus from dropdown is taken away, its value is still stored in that dropdown so that creates a problem.
can anyone suggest how do I resolve this focus issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you write this jquery function in PreSaveAction()??https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0c77954e-596a-4e66-aa6b-2f066449f338/presaveaction-is-not-firing?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Comment: No, cant we do it using javascript? I just need to check which radio button is selected.

Comment: Yes, Why not!! whatever you like jQuery/javascript you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I tried :

```
function PreSaveAction(){
prodCategory = document.getElementById('#your_id_of_dropdownchoice').value;
prodCategoryFillIn = document.getElementById('#your_id_of_fill-in_textbox').value;
prodCategoryRadio = document.getElementById('#your_id_of_dropdown_radiobutton').checked;
prodCategoryFillInRadio = document.getElementById('#your_id_of_fill-in_radiobutton').checked;

if((prodCategoryRadio==true && prodCategory =="")||(prodCategoryFillInRadio ==true && prodCategoryFillIn ==""))
{alert("your message"); return false;}

else return true;
}
```

Comment: is this working?

Comment: Yes this is working solution

Comment: Ok good then mark your answer as an answer!